# jQuery chaining custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, chain

If I have:

```
function printRangeValue(){
    $(this).prev().children("output").text( $(this).val() );
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...
    $("#strStat").printRangeValue();
    $("#conStat").printRangeValue();
});
```

```html
<label for="strStat">Strength<output id="forStr" for="strStat">12</output></label>
<input type="range" id="strStat" class="stat" name="strStat" min="3" max="20">
```

Is there a simple way to change the content of the ready function to make `$(this)` work?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `jQuery.fn.printRangeValue = function() { ... }`? Or something else? It's a little difficult to tell, because your question asks about "chaining" but you don't actually do any chaining. Your code will not work as written, but you don't mention a total failure to run, so it's difficult to tell for sure what you want.

Comment: You want to [create your own plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Comment: Okay, do you need 2 or more functions to call it a chain? If so then I'm definitely wrong about chaining, there wheren't any failurs, it just didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
    printRangeValue: function () {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).prev().children("output").text($(this).val());
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#strStat").printRangeValue();
    $("#conStat").printRangeValue();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="strStat">Strength
    <output id="forStr" for="strStat">12</output>
</label>
<input type="range" id="strStat" class="stat" name="strStat" min="3" max="20">
```

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Comment: Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/z60j538d/

Comment: It's working now, thanks!